# Alexa skill Invalid SSML Output Speech when using presigned S3 url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, alexa-skills-kit

I'm having what looks like a common problem. I'm using the sample python code generated by amazon when you create an Alexa hosted skill to generate a presigned URL for an audio file in S3 like this:

```py
url = utils.create_presigned_url(f"Media/file.mp3")

speak_output = f'<audio src="{url}"/>'
```

The URL that is generating is valid for 10 minutes and looks like this:

```
https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/88516b63-75bc-4c6a-a6cf-d12860d50b4e-eu-west-1/Media/file.mp3?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAYFCHQ4OU2ZBBLLU4%2F20200926%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200926T082211Z&X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjENH%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCWV1LXdlc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDfV53BV52momhRGAQkPJVym%2FN%2FrzPMYmCT8SOBke6CKgIhAI4AGnWd9gpzMeQb%2B1nhQ4VusLLTzs2ZNZFcMpdxaSRPKuwBCOn%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQABoMNTYwNjQzMjM2Nzc3IgzP4Hvvs9jrXQGNqCMqwAEysuGmMv8JVDGN4gUip2JPlmM7JxiEURGyhQxB9KGycK9y5hQQ6U%2BNd85W%2FZpzFksrzGagC8jJXPgJGSl0eTN1EF%2BOq%2Bk504K%2FfaSKAQr06G7Lb87CKrDFSssoUZGcztQ3oixft9Y3FMCPzd5%2FoO9AG%2BLoK2HzG2YEQyEq05aUqsNDQZG13znFpv80uLELBQc35Oy888k9PYC2tJBvMnuFpMOWr%2FZiGvZKQm8OnpYElmyHjAvY81%2Fl6CxXcuTFwRowq%2FG7%2BwU63wHmb0KR%2BPtPngH3cWgdzkBobNewKpXvczWurUPR9e73SJEjoHPS7VIkGGx6DkWXyUZIB8eOMuy0rZdnsR7MUPc6%2FMjRiqqbboLxqN%2B7vmls0tycCSe0INH%2Bo1Kkb2VZwU5kWb%2B3ZAHtzp4xERw2NQXvgVkK5gSoWbt7SGMJfjkp5cSbkxlI1aJxisgdWKWokZiU3GyqrlqVuNpRqom7ZZsuLTNOWTzUqQSx92F3ZNefJE17Jr%2Fyy6PSqA7DHRd%2Bv6Jiyuk35GSDdEeJClCofkByxnbu3da%2B8Qtnm%2FtDsUMV&X-Amz-Signature=16fa135dadc7cfa83f9bce10ffcad0e0aff7617414d88fae4b068af5cc2ebd73
```

So the final SSML returned by the function looks like:

```json
{
    "body": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "sessionAttributes": {},
        "userAgent": "ask-python/1.11.0 Python/3.7.9",
        "response": {
            "outputSpeech": {
                "type": "SSML",
                "ssml": "<speak><audio src=\"superlongurl\"/></speak>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which looks correct for me, but Alexa says:

```json
"request": {
        "type": "SessionEndedRequest",
        "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.effc325d-f969-4f3b-aa0e-d339c65ec349",
        "timestamp": "2020-09-26T08:22:12Z",
        "locale": "es-ES",
        "reason": "ERROR",
        "error": {
            "type": "INVALID_RESPONSE",
            "message": "Invalid SSML Output Speech for requestId amzn1.echo-api.request.43ec04ea-4a0c-4971-bb28-71de95141fd6. Error: Fatal error occurred when processing SSML content. This usually happens when the SSML is not well formed. Error: Unexpected character '=' (code 61); expected a semi-colon after the reference for entity 'X-Amz-Credential'\n at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,168]"
        }
    }
```

And I can't figure out why. I already read [this question](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/209567/alexa-hosted-skill-playing-mp3-file-from-s3-not-wo.html) but the solution is making the object public in your own bucket, instead of using the one provided by alexa hosted skill, which doesn't look right to me.

I also tried [this one](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/199131/playing-audio-files-from-s3-called-from-a-data-dic.html) escaping the characters with cgi (I used html package) but the response I get is:

```json
"request": {
        "type": "SessionEndedRequest",
        "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.b25a36d3-be89-4952-b688-ae2dc9b7710c",
        "timestamp": "2020-09-26T08:28:23Z",
        "locale": "es-ES",
        "reason": "ERROR",
        "error": {
            "type": "INVALID_RESPONSE",
            "message": "Invalid Audio Content for requestId amzn1.echo-api.request.5fac838c-0bd1-4704-bdaf-3cbf42d9c766. Error: The audio is not of a supported MPEG version"
        }
    }
```

Which doesn't make sense as the first URL works fine. If I try to access the escaped URL it doesn't allow me and complains about fields not present (the query params).

Does anyone has a real solution for this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with support several times and checking a lot of things. The problem was the bitrate and the sample rate of the MP3 file. You have all the requirements for the audio files here:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#audio